# Input Config File on Bluestack Mac

Tags: android, eclipse, game-engine, bluestacks

I have decided to give bluestack a try for debugging and testing my android dev games. However I have discover that the tilt doesn't seem to work.

There seem to be a few config files in the app folder, but they are for specfic game and have a classpath associated with them. eg.. com.halfbrick.jetpack.input.cfg

```
#
# Jetpack Joyride
#

[Origin]
Author  = David Reese
Rating  = 5.0

[Keys]
Space   = Tap

[Guidance]
Space   = SBoost

[GamePad]
Hat_Up      = Space
LeftStick_Up    = Space
A       = Space

[OpenSensor]
Mode    = TapA
A   = Space     SBoost

[Strings]
SBoost      = Boost

[Strings.nb_NO]
SBoost      = Gå
```

I would like to be able to test my application fully with tilt etc, but im not sure what the process is for creating one of these input files.

So my question is:

> How can I use tilt in Bluestack for Mac, for debugging and testing
>   with eclipse?

Or

> How do I create a input CFG file in bluestack for development games

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I just created a new file and named it the same as the deafult classpath of my application and used the config as below. Seemed to work fine.

```
[keys]

Q   = Tilt Absolute (-45,-45)
W   = Tilt Absolute (-45,0)
E   = Tilt Absolute (-45,45)

A   = Tilt Absolute (0,-45)
S   = Tilt Absolute (0,0)
D   = Tilt Absolute (0,45)

Z   = Tilt Absolute (45,-45)
X   = Tilt Absolute (45,0)
C   = Tilt Absolute (45,45)
```

Answer (score 0):

Aurora 2 is an Editor to generate the config mappings. See https://getsatisfaction.com/bstk/topics/aurora_a_bluestacks_keymapping_helper or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1qYU32pnb-w